# PyTorch 3 reshaping error

Tags: python, size, reshape, pytorch

When training a CNN using PyTorch in Python, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: size '[-3 x 3136]' is invalid for input with 160000 elements at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch-cpu_1515613813020/work/torch/lib/TH/THStorage.c:41
```

This is related to the x.view line in the model below:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.conv1  = nn.Conv2d(3,32,5,padding=2) # 1 input, 32 out, filter size = 5x5, 2 block outer padding
        self.conv2  = nn.Conv2d(32,64,5,padding=2) # 32 input, 64 out,  filter size = 5x5, 2 block padding
        self.fc1    = nn.Linear(64*7*7,1024) # Fully connected layer 
        self.fc2    = nn.Linear(1024,2) #Fully connected layer 2 out.

    def forward(self,x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), 2) # Max pool over convolution with 2x2 pooling 
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2) # Max pool over convolution with 2x2 pooling 
        x = x.view(-1,64*7*7) # tensor.view() reshapes the tensor
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) # Activation function after passing through fully connected layer
        x = F.dropout(x, training=True) #Dropout regularisation
        x = self.fc2(x) # Pass through final fully connected layer
        return F.log_softmax(x) # Give results using softmax

model = Net()
print(model)
```

I'm not sure if this is a result of the images having 3 channels or something else entirely. I understand that this command should reshape the images into single dimensional arrays ready for the fully connected layer so I'm not sure how to fix this issue when the error is claiming an input of 160000 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume your input images are probably of size `200x200px` (by `size` I mean here `height x width`, not taking the number of channels into account).

While your `nn.Conv2d` layers are defined to output tensors of the same size (with 32 channels for `conv1` and 64 channels for `con2`), the `F.max_pool2d` are defined in such a way they divide height and width by 2.

So after 2 max-pooling operations, your tensors are of size `200 / (2 * 2)` x `200 / (2 * 2)` = `50x50px`. With the 64 channels from `conv2`, you get `64 * 50 * 50 = 160000` elements.

Now, you need to adapt your `view()` so that it converts those inputs of shape `(batch_size, 64, 50, 50)` into `(batch_size, 64 * 50 * 50)` (to preserve the number of elements). You need to similarly adapt your 1st fully-connected layer.

```python
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.conv1  = nn.Conv2d(3,32,5,padding=2) # 1 input, 32 out, filter size = 5x5, 2 block outer padding
        self.conv2  = nn.Conv2d(32,64,5,padding=2) # 32 input, 64 out,  filter size = 5x5, 2 block padding
        self.fc1    = nn.Linear(64*50*50,1024) # Fully connected layer
        self.fc2    = nn.Linear(1024,2) #Fully connected layer 10 out.

    def forward(self,x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), 2) # Max pool over convolution with 2x2 pooling
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2) # Max pool over convolution with 2x2 pooling
        x = x.view(-1,64*50*50) # tensor.view() reshapes the tensor
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) # Activation function after passing through fully connected layer
        x = F.dropout(x, training=True) #Dropout regularisation
        x = self.fc2(x) # Pass through final fully connected layer
        return F.log_softmax(x) # Give results using softmax

model = Net()
print(model)

x = np.ones((1, 3, 200, 200))
x = torch.tensor(x)
x = model.forward(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really clearly explained! It's fixed the problem and works now.